# Shell script runs only when copying its content to a new shell script file

Tags: shell-script, postgresql

I have a shell script thats generated by a java jar that I am unable to run anything postgres related when its created.  However, when copying all of its content into a new shell script file, I am able to run the script flawlessly.  The content of the script is basically just connecting to my postgres database, creating a new database and populating it.  Here's a snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DATABASE_NAME="dbname"
export DB_USERNAME="postgres"
psql -c "drop database $DATABASE_NAME;" postgres postgres
psql -c "create database $DATABASE_NAME;" postgres postgres

echo "Starting scripts"
psql -f db/pgsql/schema/schema.sql $DATABASE_NAME $DB_USERNAME
```

Any ideas on why this is the case?

EDIT: For clarification, the script errors when it reaches this line:

> psql -c "drop database
>   $DATABASE_NAME;" postgres postgres

It is giving the following error for every line that needs to be executed in this file:

> psql: fe_sendauth: no password
>   supplied

Things I've confirmed:

- Shell script is executable
- ~/.pgpass has the necessary credentials
- If copying contents of this script to a new file and I run that file, everything runs as expected.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to execute the original shell script?

Comment: Added error into original question as "psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied"

Comment: Can you verify is the file owner same for both java generated script and the newly copied script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `diff` and `cat -v filename` to see what the differences are between the working and non-working scripts. Assuming the second "postgres" is a password, there may be something invisible that is preventing it being recognised - for example a Windows control-M (CR) line ending being used on a *Nix machine.

Comment: Thanks!  I did a cat-v filename on both files and I did find an extra character at the end of the non-working file.  The character in question is ^m, which (with a quick google search), looks to be a windows control-M.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the shell script file that is created has the **execute** bit set before you run it.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean make sure its executable? If that is the case, yes I changed it so that it is (chmod 755) and still no avail.

Comment: Does the script run if you change the permissions to 777?

Comment: Sorry Adam, changing permission to 777 still gave the password error (added into original question) when it tried executing postgres-related commands.  Please disregard previous comment

Answer (score 0):

with info from [postgres wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpass) and `psql  --help` I'm suggesting that you put your username in the .pgpass file and run the following in the script:

```
export PGPASSFILE=$HOME/.pgpass
psql -w -f db/pgsql/schema/schema.sql $DATABASE_NAME
```

PS: are you running the newly copied file by sourcing it or by running it as a binary? i.e:

```
. newfile
```

OR

```
./newfile
```